# Not Opened Measure not returning records

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, dataextensions

I want to use Measures to return Subscribers that did not open a specific email.

I sent the email to 4 Subscribers and one of the Subscribers opened the email. I can see this in the tracking view:

[image]

And also by querying the `_Open` Data View using:

```sql
SELECT SubscriberKey, EventDate
FROM _Open
WHERE JobID = 4331396
```

Which inserts one record to the target Data Extension.

So far, so good, now moving onto Measures...

If I create a Measure that looks like this:

[image]

Then I apply that measure in a Filter against the Sendable DE containing the 4 Subscribers, where my filter looks like:

[image]

(where 'Opens for 4331396' is the Measure name), then my filtered DE returns the one record that opened the email. Great.

Now, if I use the 'Not Opened' Measure:

[image]

And create a filter that looks like this:

[image]

...then I have 0 records in the Filtered DE, when I would expect to have 3 (the 3 Subscribers who did not open the email).

I'm pretty sure that my logic is correct in my filter, as it follows [this example](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_lack_of_opens_over_a_period_of_time_use_case.htm&type=5). I've also tried changing the filter expression to 'is equal to 0' but still returns 0 records.

Does anyone know why my 'Not Opened' Measure is not returning any records?

Comment: I've never been able to get the measures to work for, essentially, negative scenarios. I.e. it works with opens > 0, clicks > 0 etc. I know the details beneath, i.e. it counts records in system views,  so the "not opened" element would be equal to those in _Sent that wasn't in _Open. Would be keen to know what the answer is to this one :)

Comment: I honestly have had nothing but trouble with measures, but I have found that using greater than or equal to 0 provides the best results (although if you tried 'greater than' and then also 'equals' 0 with no results, I don't know that it will help). Measures are basically modular SQL that is run on back end based on UI input, and to my knowledge this has not been updated for nearly 10 years - so this could be a million different issues that as a user we will never be able to see.

Comment: Thanks @Gortonington, I've just refreshed the filter and it's now returning results for the 'is greater than 0' filter condition, which is odd, as it wasn't working previously (and as per my question above, I could see this open data was in the _Open data view).

Answer (score 0):

I've just refreshed the filter and it's now returning results for the 'is greater than 0' filter condition, which is odd, as it wasn't working previously.

I'm aware that open/click tracking is not real-time (more like near-time). However, this behavior is odd as the 'Open' measure was returning the correct results, but not the 'Not Opened' measure. Still, it appears to be working as expected now.

So, my answer for other users who experience the same issue is that you should try refreshing the filter at a later time.

Comment: my 'shot in the dark' guess would be that since Not Open is not a dataview, than it is a completely separate data table they have on the backend that most likely has some sort of refresh timer on it.  Meaning it will only refresh every X minutes or hours, etc. Which is why it would not show up right away on Not Open, but would on Open (which has a data view)